# Font Size in openlayers 3 cluster

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am using the new openlayers 3 api for showing a large amount of markers. I extended the cluster example (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/cluster.html).

Everything works fine except one thing: The attribute **fontSize** in the style of the text is simply ignored. The size of the text inside the cluster marker is always the same.

Is this a bug in openlayers 3 or am i doing something wrong? I tested it in the 3.0.0 release version and in the current development version of ol3.

```
    var clusters = new $wnd.ol.layer.Vector({
        source: clusterSource,
        style: function (feature, resolution) {
            var size = feature.get('features').length;

            var style = styleCache[size];
            var radius = size + 10;
            if (radius > 25) {
                radius = 25;
            }

            if (!style) {
                style = [new $wnd.ol.style.Style({
                    image: new $wnd.ol.style.Circle({
                        radius: radius,
                        stroke: new $wnd.ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: '#fff'
                        }),
                        fill: new $wnd.ol.style.Fill({
                            color: color
                        })
                    }),
                    text: new $wnd.ol.style.Text({
                        text: size == 1 ? "●" : size.toString(),
                        fontSize: radius * 2 - 5,
                        fill: new $wnd.ol.style.Fill({
                            color: textColor
                        })
                    })
                })];
                styleCache[size] = style;
            }

            return style;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `fontSize` option for `ol.style.Text`. There's a `font` option though.

The `font` option is a `string`, which has the same syntax as the Canvas context `font` attribute. The default is `'10px sans-serif'`.See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text.

So in your case you'll use something like this:

```js
var textStyle = new ol.style.Text({
  font: (radius * 2 - 5) + 'px sans-serif',
  // …
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. Could it be that the documentation is wrong then? http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0-beta.1/apidoc/ol.style.html#TextOptions

Comment: This is an old doc page. What ol3 version do you use?

Comment: The release version of 3.0.0.

Comment: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.style.Text.html The documentation of version 3.0.0 isn't quite comprehensive :) so i tried an older version.